# JUnit Running Two Projects In Eclipse

Tags: java, android, junit

I seem to have developed a strange problem in Eclipse. I have a Android project, "ExportDBSpike" with a Android test project, "ExportDBSpikeTest". Both of these need to copy a file from one location to another. As part of a different exercise I extracted the file copy functionality into a separate Java (not Android) project, "FileCopier", and added this to the build path of the Android projects. FileCopier also has some unit tests which are not part of a separate test project.

Everything works fine until I try to run the Android tests in ExportDBSpikeTest - it runs the tests which pass but then tries to run the FileCopier unit tests. These fail but this isn't the point - why and how are these tests being run?

Cheers,
Barry

Comment: UPDATE - I've separated out the FileCopier junit tests into its own project and everything seems fine now. Was this where I was going wrong - having a project house its own junit tests?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you start the unit tests and what projects are open. If you just run junit and both projects are open it will run all available unit test files.

To get around this behavior you can do one of two things:

1. Right click the non android project and press the "close project" option.

This will exclude the project from both build and test.

If this is a problem for you you can limit what tests are run by right-clicking on either the package or the individual file and go to Run As -> JUnit test

This will only run the tests in the package or file.

Comment: Well, I was right clicking the Android test project and clicking run as "Android JUnit Test". That's why I'm puzzled by it running tests in a separate project.